# What does ASM ROR do?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

What does ROR or ROL do in Assembly?
What would ROR 110100110 produce, for example?

I understand it's a 'bitwise rotation' but I have no idea what that means and have yet to find a simple example of what it does.

Comment: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-rol.html

Comment: Rotate by how far and on what operand size?

Comment: @harold The sample questions from my mock exam doesn't specify:
Following execution of the following code on an 8-bit processor, register AL will contain hexadecimal number [AL] and register BL will contain hexadecimal number [BL].

MOV AL, 55
MOV BL, CC
ROR AL

Comment: Ok so by 1 and on 8 bits, AL can't be 110100110 and apparently it is known to be 0x55 (01010101), so it would become 0xAA (10101010)

Comment: The x86 insn ref manual linked from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  It has exact details on what exactly every instruction does, down to the level of which bit goes where.

Answer (score 6):

```
ROR - Rotate Right
ROL - Rotate Left
```

In a rotate instruction, the bits that slide off the end of the register are fed back into the spaces.

**ROR**

```
mov eax,0xA //the value in eax is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
ror eax,2 // now eax will be 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010
```

**ROL**

```
mov eax,0xA //the value in eax is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
rol eax,2 // now eax will be  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 1000
```

Comment: But ROR is just plain right rotate (through carry is RCR), and `eax` is the 32bit version of the register.

Answer (score 5):

depends on the instruction set.  I assume you understand what a shift right means

110100110

shifted right one bit means bit 0 comes from bit 1 bit 1 comes from bit 2 and so on.  with a shift though the key question is where do the bits go when they fall off one end and what fills in the other end?

```
110100110
X11010011
XX1101001
XXX110100
XXXX11010
```

so a shift right the bits go to the right from a humans perspective we right numbers with the most significant on the left and least on the right.

Sometimes you will see a logical vs arithmetic shift right, etc.  The C programming language assumes zeros shift in, and you will see some instruction sets that do that, the XXes above will be zeros.  Some instruction sets also have a feature where the Carry bit is shifted in.  And some an arithmetic shift right where the msbit is shifted in, in your case that would be ones.

A ROTATE means the bits falling off one end rotate around and shift in the other.

```
110100110
X110100110
XX110100110
XXX110100110
```

so you might find an implementation where the bit shifted out is the one that shifts in the other end the above.  the first shift a zero falls off the end so the bit coming in would be a zero.  two bits shifted a 10 goes out so 10 comes in and so on:

```
110100110
011010011 0
101101001 10
110110100 110
```

you often see the Carry bit used in the rotation

```
110100110 C
C11010011 0
0C1101001 1
10C110100 1
110C11010 0
0110C1101 0
00110C110 1
100110C11 0
0100110C1 1
10100110C 1
110100110 C
```

so assuming you have a 9 bit register containing the 9 bits you specified and ROR rotates through carry then you get the above a single bit rotate puts what was in the Carry flag in the msbit the other bits in the register shift right one and the lsbit rotates into the Carry.

some instruction sets you get one bit of rotation per instruction, some let you specify an argument of how many bits rotate.  Notice the next to last value in the sequence above.  a rotate of almost all the way around is the same as a rotate left.  some instruction sets one of the rotates is actually a psuedo instruction implemented as n bits minus the rotate amount.  a rotate right of N-1 is the same as rotate left 1 kind of thing why waste an opcode.

Comment: This is instruction set/architecture specific.  Some architectures have separate instructions that rotate through carry.  When they do, I am not aware of any one of them that uses `ROR` for it.  `ROR`, unless a rotate through carry is missing, is just about always going to rotate to the most significant bit.